# Configure Traefik in docker to route subfolders

Tags: docker, docker-compose, routes, traefik

I would like to configure my Trafik installation in my docker to work with subfolders instead of subdomains. I know it should work, as I read in other posts already.
However, I don't understand what I'm doing wrong...

my docker in my test domain has the FQDN ubuntudocker.domain.qa (and I have also defined an alias for traefik.ubuntudocker.domain.qa)

This is my compose file:
The setting with subdomain works just fine, but if I use the commented-out variant with the path, it doesn't. In my browser I just get "path not found".

```YAML
version: '3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.0
    container_name: traefik
    restart: unless-stopped
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    networks:
      - proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./data/traefik.yml:/traefik.yml:ro
      - ./data/acme.json:/acme.json
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`traefik.ubuntudocker.domain.qa`)"
      #- "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`ubuntudocker.domain.qa`) && Path(`/traefik`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=api@internal"

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
```

and my traefik.yml settings file:

```YAML
api:
  dashboard: true

log:
  level: INFO

entryPoints:
  http:
    address: ":80"

providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    exposedByDefault: false
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try PathPrefix(`/traefik`) instead of Host(`traefik.ubuntudocker.domain.qa`).

Comment: Unfortunately PathPrefix(`/traefik`) doesn't work either, just like Path(`/traefik`)

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone, try to use this

(Host(`ubuntudocker.domain.qa`) && PathPrefix(`/traefik`))